# What's wrong in this discord music bot code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I just copied this code from youtube:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os, asyncio

#import all of the cogs
from help_cog import help_cog
from music_cog import music_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

#remove the default help command so that we can write out own
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
        await bot.start(os.getenv['TOKEN'])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the error

```
> await bot.start(os.getenv['TOKEN'])
> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

I think i download all the  function that's needed for this.
Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: `os.getenv['TOKEN']` -> `os.getenv()['TOKEN']`

Answer (score 4):

`os.getenv` is a function, not a list (not being subscriptable means you cannot index it like an array), you should change it from

```
os.getenv['TOKEN']
```

to

```
os.getenv('TOKEN')
```

And it should work, assuming you got everything else right.